# How to display empty or half rating star?

Tags: php, wordpress

To display the average rating of posts, I use the following code snippet.

The first part of code: with this code, I generate a variable for the average rating.

```
<?php 
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$comments = get_approved_comments( $post_id );
foreach( $comments as $comment ){
    $rate = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'rating', true );
    if( isset( $rate ) && '' !== $rate ) {
        $i++;
        $total += $rate;
        $avrating = round($total / $i, 1);
    }
}
?>
```

The second part of the code outputs rating stars.

```
<?php
global $post;
$stars   = '';
for ( $i = 1; $i <= $avrating + 1; $i++ ) {
    $width = intval( $i - $avrating > 0 ? 20 - ( ( $i - $avrating ) * 20 ) : 20 );
    if ( 0 === $width ) {
        continue;
    }
    $stars .= '<img src="mysite.com/wp-content/themes/gin_mag/img/star_little.svg" alt="">';
    if ( $i - $avrating > 0 ) {
        
    }
}
echo $stars;
?>
```

Now I have de problems. First, if the average rating is more than 5 for example 5.3 at the front, not five but six stars are displayed. I don't understand how to fix this.

And the second point, if the average rating is 2.4, three stars are displayed (star_little.svg), or it would be logical to show two full(star_little.svg) and one (halfstar_little_half.svg). I understand that this can be done implemented by checks through the if-else statement.

As I see it: If the rating is more than 2 but not 3, then display two full stars and one half. But I don't know how to implement this. Please help.

Comment: So you need ratings like 1 ,  1.5 , 2 , 2.5 , 3 ....... 4.5 and finally 5 .Is that right ?

Comment: Yes, this is right. And I need to display the stars according to these numbers.

Comment: I have added a code for rounding average based on 0.5 value